# Atributo _id y id en Base de datos

Tags: android, sqlite

Al crear una base de datos tanto de manera externa o mediante código java debemos de crear un atributo `Primary key` `Autoincrement` llamado `_id`.

Con lo cual, si yo tengo en mi base de datos relacional un `id_producto` en una tabla llamada `Productos` y deseo que `id_producto` también sea `Primary key` y `Autoincrement` no puedo ya que el atributo `_id` ya es `Primary key` con lo cual el `Primary key` de la tabla sería compuesto.

¿Como se puede gestionar esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es posible crear varias claves primarias en una tabla.

Utiliza un índice único tiene el mismo funcionamiento que una clave primaria :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pkindex ON "table1"("field1","field2");
```

Comment: Entonces en una segunda tabla a la hora de definir un `Foreign Key` a que atributo deberá de hacer referencia a `_id` o a `id_producto` ?

Comment: Por otra parte. Tal vez no es mas sencillo no usar `id_producto` u usar solamente `_id`? o esta es una mala practica en Android?

Answer (score 1):

Si no me equivoco, esto no es posible con `SQLite` sin embargo, puedes crear un `UNIQUE INDEX` que en escencia, es lo mismo que un Primary key

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX primary_key ON "tu_tabla"("_id","producto_id");
```

Comment: Entonces en una segunda tabla a la hora de definir un `Foreign Key` a que atributo deberá de hacer referencia a `_id` o a `id_producto` ? 

Por otra parte. Tal vez no es mas sencillo no usar `id_producto` u usar solamente `_id`? o esta es una mala practica en Android?